# How to map violin sounds to midi notes

Tags: violin, midi

There are some violin sounds available here :

https://philharmonia.co.uk/resources/sound-samples/

For A3 many mp3 files are given:

**File Name, duration in seconds**

```
violin_A3_025_forte_arco-normal, 0.8359166666666666

violin_A3_025_fortissimo_arco-normal, 1.2539166666666666

violin_A3_025_mezzo-forte_arco-normal, 1.0971666666666666

violin_A3_025_mezzo-piano_arco-normal, 0.8881666666666667

violin_A3_025_pianissimo_arco-normal, 1.0971666666666666

violin_A3_025_piano_arco-normal, 1.0449166666666667

violin_A3_05_forte_arco-normal, 0.862

violin_A3_05_fortissimo_arco-normal, 1.22775

violin_A3_05_pianissimo_arco-normal, 0.9404166666666667

violin_A3_05_piano_arco-normal, 1.12325

violin_A3_15_forte_arco-normal, 1.1494166666666668

violin_A3_15_fortissimo_arco-normal, 2.272666666666667

violin_A3_1_forte_arco-normal, 1.6195833333333334

violin_A3_1_fortissimo_arco-normal, 1.4628333333333334

violin_A3_1_pianissimo_arco-normal, 1.01875

violin_A3_1_piano_arco-normal, 0.9926666666666667

violin_A3_phrase_forte_arco-spiccato, 0.862

violin_A3_phrase_forte_arco-staccato, 0.8098333333333333

violin_A3_phrase_fortissimo_arco-au-talon, 2.3249166666666667

violin_A3_phrase_fortissimo_arco-martele, 2.0636666666666668

violin_A3_phrase_mezzo-forte_arco-tenuto, 0.9926666666666667

violin_A3_phrase_mezzo-forte_arco-tremolo, 3.2914166666666667

violin_A3_phrase_mezzo-piano_arco-detache, 1.0449166666666667

violin_A3_phrase_mezzo-piano_arco-legato, 0.9665
```

My question is how to map these mp3 files to Midi notation?
Like :

2, 120, Note_on_c, 0, 53, 100

2, 240, Note_on_c, 0, 53, 0

I know some of the name meanings. Like 'piano' means quiet.
How to map these files into 0-127 volume scale.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'map 'here? How to get midi parameters from a name? Are you only interest in the volume (in that case there musicamante's answer)? Are you trying to use these sounds with a midi file (which is backward to the first)?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic, just like time/tempo, is **always** relative: *pp* or *ff* don't mean a specific "loudness".

For audio samples the rule is the same: it depends on the context.

You can decide a basic *ratio", based on the softer and louder samples, and decide the actual velocity to assign to those samples, but keep in mind that the loudness is **always** based on perception.

The rule of thumb is to consider a 0.0-1.0 range, where 0.0 is the softer sample reference and 1.0 the louder.

For standard dynamics, consider the following ranges:

- pianissimo
- piano
- mezzo piano
- mezzo forte
- forte
- fortissimo

Since there's a 6-span range, the standard result *should* be:

```
- pianissimo:   0.0   -   0.166  (  0 - 21)
- piano:        0.166 -   0.33   ( 22 - 42)
- mezzo piano:  0.33  -   0.5    ( 43 - 63)
- mezzo forte:  0.5   -   0.66   ( 64 - 85)
- forte:        0.66  -   0.833  ( 86 - 106)
- fortissimo:   0.833 -   1.0    (107 - 127)
```

Values in parentheses are MIDI velocity numbers (in 0-127 range).

Obviously it all depends on how the samples were recorded and produced, so the ranges above will probably change: it's up to you to decide how to correct those values.